# Migrating JSON to drupal 8 nodes using Migrate modules

Tags: php, json, api, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am using the migrate_plus and migrate_tools modules to try to import product from a JSON file to a Product content type in Drupal 8.

I am following this tutorial: https://colorfield.be/blog/drupal-8-json-custom-migration

So if I am using the JSON file from that tutorial, everything is working fine. Now I am trying to use my own JSON file, importing from a Rest API.

The structure is as follows:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "dutchname": "Name of the product",
        "purchaseprice": "30.00",
        "description": "Description of the product",
    }, etc. etc. etc.
```

I have a few products like these in that array.

Now I am using the following (sorry wasn't able to put that in a codeblock??):

[image]

Now I am getting a huge error in my console, too long to output here, but it starts with something like:

```
QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {node_field_data}
```

What is wrong in my code, and why?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: By default Drupal 8 content types have a title field. Try add it in your yml, even with a "-"

Comment: But isn't that generated by the 'title: dutchname' that I have in my code? Also the tutorial also doesn't have a title field up there with the '-'

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't see that. That looks correct to me

Comment: Anyone that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've specified that the title field should be populated by dutchname, if the dutchname value is NULL for a particular row in your source data, then that specific row can generate the error.  Check to make sure that you don't have any NULL values for dutchname in your source data.